# Is there a JavaScript way to set the time for this jQuery timepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I would like to set the current date/time to populate automatically into the input textbox according to the same format used by this timepicker plugin:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

The plugin assumes that you want the input text field to appear blank until the user interacts with it.

```
$('#example2').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true
});
```

But I want the input text field to already contain the current date and time:

```
05/16/2011 04:00 am
```

The only way I can see to do this at the moment is using my server-side scripting language.

But ideally there should be a way to do this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided, it shows you how to specify the time:

```
$('#example7').datetimepicker({
    hour: 13,
    minute: 15
});
```

A quick way would be to set the value of the text box within the HTML markup, e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="example7" value="05/16/2011 04:00" />
```

Or it could be done with JQuery:

```
$('#example7').val("05/16/2011 04:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#yourcontrol').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

to set the control with current date and time.